# How would I check to see if any value from range 1 is present in range 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working in Excel 2010 and I THINK the solution is achievable using the mystical sumproduct formula, but I'm terrible at sumproduct beyond it's most basic application.

- What I'm trying to do conceptually: scan the 5 columns of data in
  "range 2", for any one of the values in "range 1". If any one of the values from range 1 is present in range 2, return a value of 1 or other positive indication.
- I have 5 columns of data (continuous/connected) that I'm performing the logical test on
- I have 5-10 values (not continuous) that I'm checking for (The number of values I'm
  testing won't necessarily match the number of columns I'm checking)

Or, put another way, how might I perform a countif using multiple criteria, but without having to re enter the criteria range - over and over and over and over?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if any values from `range1` are within `range2`, enter this as an array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER):

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(range1,range2))>0
```

To determine the number of matching values, remove `>0`.

---

**Example 1:**

**elephant** is in both columns:

[image]

---

**Example 2:**

There are no matching elements between columns:

[image]

---

**Example 3:**

There are two matching elements (elephant and gargoyle):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(RANGE2,RANGE1CELL1)>0,"Found","Not Found")
```